# Is possible to convert .ui file (Qt designer) to xml Android?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, qt, qt-designer

I created a layout with buttons,tables,labels etc with Qt Designer, around 1400 lines of code.

Is possible to convert this .ui file to xml in order to use same GUI on android devices?

Comment: It's not impossible, but sounds pretty difficult. You'd need to write the parser your self in order to convert it.

Comment: Or you can use [Qt on Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html) and keep your original ui